# what is causing segmentation fault in c code, dynamic allocation accross functions

Tags: c, dynamic, segmentation-fault

I am trying to have dynamically allocate arrays of structures and perform operations on them but i keep running into segmentation faults. could someone help me out?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void *malloc(size_t size);

typedef struct {
  double x;
  double y;
} coords;

struct figure {
  char fig_name[128];
  int coordcount, size_tracker;
  coords *pointer;
} fig;

void init_fig(int n, struct figure **point)
{
  printf("%u\n", sizeof(coords));
  point[n]->pointer = malloc(sizeof(coords) * 20);  <-------SEGFAULT
  if (point[n]->pointer == NULL){
    exit(-1);
  }
  point[n]->pointer[19].x = 2;
  point[n]->pointer[0].x = 1;
  point[n]->pointer[0].y = 2;
  point[n]->pointer[7].x = 100;
}

int main()
{
  int numfigs = 1;
  struct figure * point;
  point = malloc(sizeof(struct figure) * 16);
  point = &fig;
  point[1].coordcount = 1;
  init_fig(numfigs, &point);
  return 0;
}
```

I labelled where the first seg fault occurs, (used ddd). what i dont get is that i can manipulate  point[1] in main but not in any other function.

Comment: this is not my project it is simply a short test file ive been using to try and figure out why im geting seg faults

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with @Maxim Skurydin.
Nevertheless I'd like to explain your mistake in some more details.

Reading your `init_fig` one assumes that the parameter you pass `struct figure **point` - is actually *array of pointers* to `struct figure`. And this function accesses its `n`'th element.

However in your `main` you do something else. You allocate an *array of* `struct figure`, and your `point` variable points to its head. Then you take the address of this local variable and call your `init_fig`.

Here's the problem. `init_fig` assumes that you pass it an array of pointers, whereas actually this "array" consists of a single element only: the local `point` variable declared in `main`.

**EDIT:**

How to do this properly.

1. Leave `main` intact, fix `init_fig`.

This means that **actually** there's an array of `figure` structs. Means - a single memory block, interpreted as an array of consequent structs.

```
void init_fig(int n, struct figure *point)
{
  printf("%u\n", sizeof(coords));
  point[n].pointer = malloc(sizeof(coords) * 20);  <-------SEGFAULT
  if (point[n].pointer == NULL){
    exit(-1);
  }
  point[n].pointer[19].x = 2;
  point[n].pointer[0].x = 1;
  point[n].pointer[0].y = 2;
  point[n].pointer[7].x = 100;
}
```

1. Leave `init_fig` intact. Fix `main`.

This means that we actually should allocate an array of pointers, every such a pointer should point to an allocated `point` structure.

```
int main()
{
  int numfigs = 1;
  struct figure ** point;
  point = malloc(sizeof(struct figure*) * 16);

  for (i = 0; i < 16; i++)
    point[i] = malloc(sizeof(struct figure));

  point[1].coordcount = 1;
  init_fig(numfigs, &point);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: hmm.. do you mind me asking how I do this properly then? should my functions take in a struct figure *point? or should I initialize a struct figure **point in main. sorry im a bit new to this.

Comment: ok i did option 1 but now I can assign things to point[n].pointer[233] which is far outside the allocated 20. why does this work? should i have a seg fault?
    
      point[n].pointer[233].x = 2;
      printf("%lf\n", point[n].pointer[233].x);

Comment: @user1787262 Writing or reading outside the allocated memory is undefined behaviour. It crashes immediately if you're very lucky, it corrupts important data and crashes later if you're less lucky. Just don't do it.

Comment: okay,thank goodness you explained that there. I had originally done my program the way you described above but was confused when I could write outside my allocated bound. but now that you explained it I understand THANK YOU! @DanielFischer

Answer (score 0):

You allocate memory and store the pointer in `point` but then you forget that pointer when you assign `&fig` to it.

```
point = malloc(sizeof(struct figure) * 16);
point = &fig;
```

So, you are essentially trying to write `fig[1]`, that does not make sense.

Answer (score 0):

```
  struct figure * point;
  point = malloc(sizeof(struct figure) * 16);
```

here point is pointer pointing to memory of 16 structures in heap
but in the next line you have done this

```
  point = &fig;
```

so its memory leak and also point is not pointing to that allocated region anymore

and also `init_fig` should be like this

```
void init_fig(int n, struct figure **point)
```

It's the problem of segfault

Answer (score 0):

Eliminate this line `point = &fig;`

and modify the function:

```
void init_fig(int n, struct figure *point)
{
  ...
  point[n].pointer = (coords*) malloc(sizeof(coords) * 20);
  ...
}
```

since you should pass an array of structs and not an array of pointers.

Also, add a third parameter to the init_fig function so you can pass the size of the array of points that you want to create. Like :

```
void init_fig(int n, struct figure *point, int size)
    {
      ...
      point[n].pointer = (coords*) malloc(sizeof(coords) * size);
      ...
    }
```

Therefore, making the function more reusable.

Modify also the call to that function:

```
init_fig(numfigs, &point); to init_fig(numfigs, point);
```